# Is the inverse of a symmetric matrix also symmetric?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, symmetric-matrices

Let $A$ be a symmetric invertible matrix, $A^T=A$, $A^{-1}A = A A^{-1} = I$ Can it be shown that $A^{-1}$ is also symmetric?

I seem to remember a proof similar to this from my linear algebra class, but it has been a long time, and I can't find it in my text book.

Answer (score 131, accepted):

In fact, $(A^T)^{-1}=(A^{-1})^T$. Indeed, $A^T(A^{-1})^T=(A^{-1}A)^T=I$.

Answer (score 211):

You can't use the thing you want to prove in the proof itself, so the above answers are missing some steps. Here is a more detailed and complete proof.

Given A is nonsingular and symmetric, show that $ A^{-1} = (A^{-1})^T $.

Since $A$ is nonsingular, $A^{-1}$ exists. Since $ I = I^T $ and $ AA^{-1} = I $,

$$ AA^{-1} = (AA^{-1})^T. $$

Since $ (AB)^T = B^TA^T $,

$$ AA^{-1} = (A^{-1})^TA^T. $$

Since $ AA^{-1} = A^{-1}A = I $, we rearrange the left side to obtain

$$ A^{-1}A = (A^{-1})^TA^T. $$

Since $A$ is symmetric, $ A = A^T $, and we can substitute this into the right side to obtain

$$ A^{-1}A = (A^{-1})^TA. $$

From here, we see that

$$ A^{-1}A(A^{-1}) = (A^{-1})^TA(A^{-1})$$
$$ A^{-1}I = (A^{-1})^TI $$
$$ A^{-1} = (A^{-1})^T, $$

thus proving the claim.

Answer (score 33):

Yes.

$$
AB=BA=I\quad\Rightarrow\quad B^TA^T=A^TB^T=I\quad\Rightarrow\quad B^TA=AB^T=I
$$

Answer (score 27):

Yes. The inverse $A^{-1}$ of invertible symmetric matrix is also symmetric:

\begin{align}
A & = A^T  &&\text{(Assumption: $A$ is symmetric)}\\ \\
A^{-1} & = (A^T)^{-1} &&\text{($A$ invertible $\implies A^T = A$ invertible)}\\ \\
A^{-1} & = (A^{-1})^T &&\text{(Identity: $(A^T)^{-1} = (A^{-1})^T$)} \\ \\
{\large \therefore}\quad \rlap{\text{If $A$ is symmetric and invertible, then $A^{-1}$ is symmetric.}}
\end{align}

Answer (score 24):

Another way to see that is to recall the formula $$A^{-1} = \frac{1}{\det(A)} \mathrm{Adj}(A)^T$$ and to note that the adjoint matrix of a symmetric matrix is by construction symmetric.

Answer (score 20):

All the proofs here use algebraic manipulations. But I think it may be more illuminating to think of a symmetric matrix as representing an operator consisting of *a rotation, an anisotropic scaling and a rotation back*. This is provided by the **Spectral theorem**, which says that any symmetric matrix is diagonalizable by an orthogonal matrix. With this insight, it is easy to see that the inverse of the operator is a similar three-step sequence. Finally, we need to establish that any such three-step sequence produces a symmetric matrix: given any orthogonal matrix $V$ and diagonal matrix $D$, $(V D V^T)^T = V D V^T$. Hence the inverse of a symmetric matrix is also symmetric.

Comment: Very nice intuitive answer. The reason this is getting fewer upvotes is that it’s posted much later than the others. That doesn’t stop this from being a good answer though.

Answer (score 6):

We have two properties to use: $A^{T}=A$ and $A^{-1} $exist, here we go!

$$
A^{-1}A=I
$$since $A^{-1}$exist
$$
(A^{-1}A)^{T}=A^{T}(A^{-1})^{T}=A(A^{-1})^{T}=I^{T}=I
$$since $A^{T}=A$
$$
A^{-1}A(A^{-1})^{T}=A^{-1}I
$$left multiply by $A^{-1}$

Thus
$$I(A^{-1})^{T}=(A^{-1})^{T}=A^{-1}$$

Answer (score 3):

Inverse of $A$ can be expressed as a polynomial $p(A)$ of $A$ (from Cayley-Hamilton theorem).

So it is sufficient to prove that if $A$ is symmetric then power $A^k$ is symmetric, sum of symmetric matrices is symmetric and multiply by scalar is symmetric.

Comment: I.e. for symmetric $A,B$  $(A^k)^T=A^k,(tA)^T=tA, (A+B)^T=A+B, $

Answer (score 1):

$$
(AA^{-1})^T=I^T=I=(A^{-1})^TA^T=(A^{-1})^TA=I\quad\Rightarrow\quad(A^{-1})^T=IA^{-1}\quad\Rightarrow\quad(A^{-1})^T=A^{-1}
$$
By definition
$$A=A^T$$
Used linear algebra equations
$$(AB)^T=B^TA^T;AA^{-1}=I;I^T=I$$

Answer (score 1):

Every symmetric matrix $A$ can be decomposed as $VDV^T$, where $V$ is orthogonal($V^T=V^{-1}$)

$$\begin{split}
   A^{-1}&=(VDV^T)^{-1} \\
   &=(V^{T})^{-1}D^{-1}V^{-1}\\
   &=VD_{1}V^{T}    (D_{1}=D^{-1})
\end{split}$$
Inverse of a diagonal matrix can be found by taking reciprocals of all the entries of diagonal matrix. We can see that $A^{-1}$ has the same form as $A$ except that $D$ is replaced by $D_{1}$. So,inverse of a symmetrix matrix is symmetric.

Comment: That is correct, for *real* matrices. But that uses a hard theorem (the spectral theorem), whereas the statement holds for matrices over *any* field and it is very easy to prove.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is. Proof:

Since $A$ is invertible we can write

$A A^{-1} = I$.

Taking the transpose on both sides, using the identity $(AB)^T = B^T A^T$, we get

$(A^{-1})^T A^T = I$.

Because $A$ is symmetric, we can replace $A^T$ by $A$,

$(A^{-1})^T A = I$.

Right-multiplying by $A^{-1}$ yields

$(A^{-1})^T = A^{-1}$

which shows that the inverse of $A$ is symmetric.