# The inverse of a symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am trying to simplify this expression where
$$
(X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T)^T = X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T
$$
should hold.
However, I am not sure what to do with $((X^TX)^{-1})^T$ once I make the transpose notation into the bracket. Any hint/help would be really appreiciated!

Comment: The inverse of a symmetric matrix is also symmetric. See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/325082/is-the-inverse-of-a-symmetric-matrix-also-symmetric).

Comment: Also this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/340233/transpose-of-inverse-vs-inverse-of-transpose

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any invertible matrix $A$, [we have](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/340234/872872):
$$(A^T)^{-1}=(A^{-1})^T\ .
$$

Now, let $A=X^TX$. Then since $A^T=A$, we have
$$
(A^{-1})^T=A^{-1}\ .
$$